# Ralink 539b no wifi

Tags: wireless, ralink

I just installed ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop and i can't get wifi. I installed the  bcmwl kernal- driver thing and it still didn't work my bluetooth doesn't work either, which driver do i need and can somebody show me how to install it. help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've looked everywhere for a solution and this finally worked for my g7-2215dx Thank you to
whoever posted this answer I can now enjoy linux with wireless!!!!

Answer (score 1):

According to this here - https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/222095 The solution is to install a kernel from 12.10 into 12.04 with this command below.

sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-quantal linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal

Then reboot, If wireless still does not work run - sudo modprobe rt2800pci